# Why login is not working after deploying symfony project on different server?

Tags: symfony1, passwords, hosting

I have a website developed using Symfony framework by some other developers. I have configured it successfully on one of my hosting server. And it is working fine. It has some sort of security feature applied so that it asks for login when we open the site. Just like `.htpasswd` security but haven't found that `.htpasswd` file anywhere.

Now, I deployed same site using same steps on another dedicated server where it deployed successfully, I can even open the backend as it do not asks for login details. But when I open the frontend, it asks for login details. I entered the same login details which worked on previous server but it is not working due to some reason.

Can anyone suggest me how this security is given? And what should be the steps to remove this security ?

Comment: Which kind of web server, apache1, apache2, nginx? It might be a restriction from the vhost configuration if you can't find it in symfony itself.

Comment: ok, its Apache2 Web server on Ubuntu Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed up the issue, it was with the Auth filter created by previous developer. Just disabled it inside filters.yml file. Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

In Symfony 1.x, you can disable login by setting the is_secure option to false,
this is found in security.yml file in the config folder.

```
default:
  is_secure: true
```

I'm not sure if removing the password protection is the right thing to do here though.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` of the first server (the one where every thing is ok), open the file related to your website and compare it to the same file on the server where it's not working.

You might find a directive called `AuthUserFile`.

Also, show us your `.htaccess` where the auth can be too.

Comment: the weird thing is, the server on which site configured fine is shared hosting, so I have no access to the apache files. Though it configured pretty straight forward

Comment: Well, in that case you should take a look into your admin panel I guess

Comment: is that something to do with "uploads" folder? as when I open some modules of Admin Panel, they load images from Upload folder and for loading those images, it is asking to log in.

Comment: I have sent u a tweet, please check it :)

Comment: I didn't see anything related to auth in this htaccess.

Comment: I see there is the "auth" settings inside app.yml file. And it has same login details which I is working on other server. See if this helps some way?